# How to change dependency versions accepted in package

Tags: react-native, expo, node-modules

I have an expo project using rn-pdf-reader-js with what is below (in package-lock.json)

```
"node_modules/rn-pdf-reader-js": {
  "version": "4.1.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/rn-pdf-reader-js/-/rn-pdf-reader-js-4.1.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-KnBzB1wfHPdE/Qb6oMmX0/iAD60tp+kf0TZaHw6tb0ULrdSvaG5rspTJArUEA724qYFwuVG1U2B0WTK8inpe1Q==",
  "dependencies": {
    "buffer": "5.1.0",
    "csstype": "2.6.8",
    "js-base64": "2.4.5"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "expo": ">= 33.0.x < 37.0.x",
    "expo-constants": ">= 5.0.0 < 9.x",
    "expo-file-system": ">= 5.0.0 < 9.x",
    "react": "16.x",
    "react-native": "*",
    "react-native-webview": ">= 7.0.5 < 8.x"
  }
},
```

However I am using expo version 47.0.9

So, I was wondering if I can just edit the peerDependencies for rn-pdf-reader-js to be "expo": ">= 33.0.x < 50.0.x" instead of "expo": ">= 33.0.x < 37.0.x"

I ask because everytime I would install any other dependency I would get an error saying rn-pdf-reader-js is not compatible and then I would have to install with --legacy-peer-deps. This works fine in the expo-go app (the app runs normally) and although the package rn-pdf-reader-js is supposedly outdated I don't see any issues.

However now I cannot build my project because that runs npm install which throws the error

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'children')
```

Is this the correct approach to fixing the issue and not having to use --legacy-peer-deps for everything?

Comment: I think the library is not compatible with your current project. You should look for alternative instead of modify the package lock file. Or you can follow up with the library own is there plan to support latest expo version.

Comment: @EdwinWong Do you know of a good alternative that works with expo? This was the only one I found to work which is why I am going so far to make it work...

Comment: I have no idea. But you can check the library from here https://reactnative.directory/